# Finder preferences are ignored

Tags: finder

After installing the latest version of the [driver](https://www.asix.com.tw/en) for my [AmazonBasics USB-Ethernet Adapter](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00M77HMU0/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) my Finder sidebar has removed a bunch of folders and I can't figure out how to get them back.

I checked my preferences and everything is still listed.

How do I get them back?

[image: Preferences vs Actuals]

I am running macOS 11.5 on a macbook pro (mid-2015).

[image: Macbook info]

Comment: Just click on Favorites on sidebar to expand/open it and there they are (or should be :-))

Answer (score 1):

Hover your cursor next to Favourites, then click Show

[image]